# Proving/disproving a Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Please be kind. I am still new to writing proofs, and my logic might be scattered(if there is any logic).

I am to prove the set $7\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring with respect to the usual operations of addition and multiplication. I do not have to verify associativity, commutativity, or distributivity(homework instructions notes that I can skip this). I do, however, have to prove the set is closed under multiplication and addition.

Logic:
Since I do not have to prove associativity, commutativity, or distributivity, would that imply that I only have to prove that under addition, there is an inverse of $0$ and multiplication there is an inverse of $1$?

Proof(attempt): Let $a$ be an element in $\mathbb{Z}$. Then, there exist an element $-a$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, such that $a+(-a)$ = $0$.

For multiplication,
Proof(attempt): Let a be an element in $\mathbb{Z}$. If there is an element $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $1$ is not zero and $1a = a1 = a$ for each $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Sorry, if this is completely scattered. I am really brand new to proofs and just trying to tie everything together. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

EDIT: Sorry, I meant identity for inverse.

Comment: Does the ring have to have unity? In this case, you’re looking at the set $R=7\Bbb Z$ and you are trying to prove that with the usual addition and multiplication, $R$ is, in fact, a ring (not just a set). So for any element in $R$ you need an additive inverse...you give elements for $\Bbb Z$, not $7\Bbb z$

Comment: It does not mention whether it has to have unity. I just need to prove $7\mathbb{Z}$ is closed under multiplication and addition, and if the set is a ring.

Answer (score 1):

Let's recall what being *closed* under an operation means. If you have an binary operation in a set $X$, that is a function $u: X \times X \rightarrow  X$; and a subset $Y \subseteq X$, then $Y$ is *closed* under $u$ if:

$$
u(y_1,y_2) \in Y \quad (\forall y_1,y_2 \in Y)
$$

intuitively, the operation sends elements in $Y$ to an element that lies again on $Y$. In particular in you example, we have $7\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ and the usual product and sum operations in the integers. Therefore, what you have to prove is that, if $k,l \in 7\mathbb{Z}$, then $k\cdot l \in 7\mathbb{Z}$ and $k+l \in \mathbb{Z}$. In effect, if $k$ and $l$ are elements of $7\mathbb{Z}$, they are multiples of seven, concretely:

$$
k = 7r, \quad l = 7s \quad \text{ for some } r,s \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

therefore,

$$
k+l = 7r + 7s = 7(r+s) \in 7\mathbb{Z}
$$

and

$$
k\cdot l = (7r)(7s) = 7(r7s) \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

as we wanted to show.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am following along some notes from my book and it states that it needs to satisfy the following conditions: a + b = b+ a for a,b in R. (a+b) + c = a+(b+c) for a,b,c in $\mathbb{R}$. There is an element 0 in R such that a+0 = a for all a in R. For every element a in R, there exists an element -a in R such that a+(-a)=0. (ab)c = a(bc) for a,b,c in R. For a,b,c in R, a(b+c) = ab+ac and (a+b)c = ac+bc. Since my I do not have to verify associativity, commutativity, or distributivity, what is left for me to prove? I am not exactly understanding.

Comment: All these properties indeed define a ring, in that regard you are correct. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring, these properties hold in particular for *some* of the elements, such as the ones in $7\mathbb{Z}$. What you need to prove, however, is that if you do the sum or the product of elements in $7\mathbb{Z}$ , the result will again be an element of $7\mathbb{Z}$: that is, that $7\mathbb{Z}$ is closed under addition and multiplication (as you stated in your post).

Comment: (cont.) to be more concrete, a ring $(R,+, \cdot)$ is a set with operations $+,\cdot$ from $R \times R$ to $R$ that behave as you've described. If we want to obtain a *subring* $S \subseteq R$ from a given ring, we can restrict the operations $\times,\cdot$ to elements on $S$, but we then have to verify that the codomain can also be restricted to $S$ in this case, so that we obtain new operations that have domain $S \times S$ and codomain $S$.

Comment: (cont. pt. II) It's also worth mentioning that some definitions of ring include the existence of $1$ and some do not. If your definition is the former, clearly $7\mathbb{Z}$ is not a subring since $1 \not \in 7\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help and clarification. I will give it a second attempt.

Comment: Is the last line in the equation above correct? That is, (7r)(7s) = 7(r7s)?

Comment: I think so, what makes you think there is a mistake?

Comment: I apologize, it is late and I completely spaced out. Thanks for your time and clarification.

Comment: No problem! My intention was to understand at which step were you stuck. I hope this has provided at least a tiny bit of insight. Cheers.